# What happens if no one wants to advise me?

Tags: phd, advisor

I was accepted to a PhD program. I am finished with quals and looking for an advisor. I'm having a difficult time finding one though. Everyone is not accepting students (or at least not me). It's a small department. I'm worried I won't find ANYONE to advise me. I finished my quals, I work hard, I try to be polite.

If no one wants to advise me, do I just have to drop out?

Comment: Who knows? This most certainly depend on your country, your university, your department...

Comment: I guess that will depend on the rules of your institution. Don't you have someone to ask?

Comment: It matters enormously whether "no one will advise me" means on a project  you yourself have already chosen, or something else. If you already have your mind set on a particular project that either seems unwise or at least too distant from the expertise of any faculty, then they are reasonable to decline. But if it's truly that no one is accepting _any_ students under any condition, you should tell the "Director of Grad Studies" in your department, and ask advice there.

Comment: I'm not aware of any students in my (large) department being unable to find an adviser, but I'm pretty sure that, if such a situation occurred, the chair of our doctoral committee would start talking to potential advisers (people somewhat close to the student's interests and not already advising too many students) to try to get one of them to agree to advise this student. If that failed (which seems unlikely), I think the chair of the department would start leaning on people to take this student.

Comment: I'm not sure if this comes from the US, but I know there are globally programs that don't require an advisor for all PhD students, even if this possibility is seldom advertised. From your question it would not seem you have investigated this option.

Comment: Definitely talk to the dean of graduate studies.  But also see if you can find someone in another department with affinity for your area.  Here's one possible way that could work out for you: the outside advisor might work with you closely, and be on your committee, but your department might find someone in your department to be your nominal advisor.  This person would be playing a minor role and might therefore be willing to make the commitment.  Another possible scenario: the outside advisor might get a joint appointment and come into the fold of your department.  Etc.

Answer (score 23):

You have to have an advisor to continue in the program, and advising needs to be a mutually consensual relationship.  So if it really happens that absolutely nobody will advise you, then you'll need to leave the program (but you could probably transfer to another one).

But in practice, it should very rarely get to that point.  Your program should have a graduate chair or some similarly-titled faculty member who is in charge of the PhD program.  Talk to this person.  There are a couple of possibilities:

- There are faculty who would be interested in working with you in principle, but they feel too busy.  The graduate chair can try to convince them, and exert pressure.  If the department is interested in having a good PhD program at all, they won't want to lose good students for no good reason; so eventually someone should be willing to take you on.  Maybe other workload bargaining will happen behind the scenes (e.g. Professor Smith says "I'll advise the student, but I want to be excused from serving on Committee A.")
- There is something about your academic background or personal style that makes faculty reluctant to work with you.  This is less likely; if there were serious issues you probably wouldn't have made it this far in the program.  (In particular, you've passed quals, which is a very good sign.)  But if there is some issue like that, the graduate chair should be able to talk to you about it honestly; and then you can work on addressing it.
- Least likely possibility: the program is totally dysfunctional, and faculty members don't really want to invest any effort in working with grad students, or are so completely overwhelmed with other duties that they cannot.  Hopefully this is not the case, but if after talking with enough people (including those at other institutions) you become sure that this is what is going on, then you should transfer to another program as soon as you can.

Comment: In practice, it _does_ sometimes get to that point. Among my mother's PhD classmates, for example, almost half left ABD because they could not secure an advisor. (The school eventually shut down that particular PhD program because of the low graduation rates.)

Comment: @ff524: Yeah, I changed it to "very rarely".  That situation would fall under my third bullet.

Comment: One other possibility: no one wants to advise the student, because the student isn't interested / willing to work on any of the topics/projects that the faculty are interested in or have funding for.  If no faculty member wants to advise you, one thing to check is whether you're being too picky about what topics/projects you're willing to work on.  It's hard to tell from the question whether that might apply here.  I'd suggest editing the answer to add this additional possibility (or I can do it for you if you prefer; I just didn't want to make a change of this magnitude without your OK).

Comment: @D.W. It's also possible that the student is *not particularly talented* for the topics that the faculty is interested in.  Say, if the student is strong in applied subjects, but weaker in theory, then it doesn't help that some faculty member who is working in theory is willing to advise some more students.

Comment: @D.W. That's very subject dependent. I guess you are thinking most obviously of science subjects. It is possible in e.g. humanities, but much less likely. However, it does matter that the general area of the chosen topic is something the advisor know about. (Or that somebody else is available to co-advise or whatever.)